# strtolower inside preg_replace - possible?

Tags: php

Is it possible to use `strtolower` in the substitution part of `preg_replace`?

This isn’t working:

```
preg_replace('/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org|tv|biz)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?&=#\+;]+)*)/i', '<a href="http://www.'.strtolower('$3').'" target="_blank">'.strtolower('$3').'</a>', $d);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, yes. Have a look at the `e` modifier ([Example #4](https://www.php.net/preg-replace#function.preg-replace.examples)):

```
preg_replace('/(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|org|tv|biz)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?&=#\+;]+)*)/ie', "'<a href=\"http://www.'.strtolower('$3').'\" target=\"_blank\">'.strtolower('$3').'</a>'", $d);
```

(Untested, the number of escaping backslashes may be wrong.)

Comment: Thank you so much jensgram!
Spot on except you only need to escape the " once (single backslash).

nice one!

Answer (score 2):

I favor using preg_replace_callback() over using the e(eval) modifier. I feel the code is cleaner, and has less room for error.

Comment: +1 I'm tempted to agree with you. Only problem is that the syntax for anonymous function in PHP is not much cleaner, IMO :)

Comment: Ya, create_function() is ugly. But in php 5.3+, anonyous functions are pretty nice. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php