# Combine preg _replace and strtolower

Tags: php

I try to combine `strtolower` and `preg_replace`, but I am not sure how to nest it. I have tried it like so:

```
$res = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string));
```

I found [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412222/strtolower-inside-preg-replace-possible) but cannot get it to work. I want a lowercase string without special characters:

> I am some special-content

turns into

> iamsomespecialcontent

How can I achieve this and store it inside `$res`?

Comment: Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Whichever function is nested the deepest will occur first.  In this case as your code is now, the `preg_replace` happens first, then `preg_replace`'s output is converted to lower, and output to `$res`.

Comment: I do not know why the code above does not work, but I solved it using two lines: `$string = strtolower(get_sub_field('a-pikto'));
           $res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);`…

Comment: [**norepro**](https://3v4l.org/Efqen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to split this into a two-liner and debug the output of the commands with var_dump() in order to see whats going on:

```
<?php

/* string with special chars */
$string = 'abczABCZ-#+´!"§123';

$no_special_chars = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string); 

var_dump($no_special_chars);    // string 'abczABCZ' (length=8)   

$lowercased = strtolower($no_special_chars);

var_dump($lowercased);          // string 'abczabcz' (length=8)
```

And maybe you noticed, that you don't have to handle `A-Z` in the preg_replace(), if you lowercase the string first.

```
$res = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/", "", strtolower($string));

var_dump($res); // string 'abczabcz' (length=8)
```

Comment: You could also pass `i` modifier to preg_replace code: 
`preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $string); `

Answer (score 1):

Well I can say first step will be making string as lowercase

```
$rest = strtolower($string);
```

And then removing white spaces

```
$rest = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $rest);
```

You can combine it as -

```
$rest = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", strtolower($rest));
```

For more special character related solution you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: This is not stripping the special chars, just the spaces. There is no function lowercase - http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=lowercase